# Reorder an array according to given index in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am facing problem to change the index values of an array according to given index in javaScript. i have searched on StackOverflow and found some solution but those not working for me of are not for javaScript. The below input array and index is mentioned.

```
   Input:  arr[]   = [101, 102, 103];
   index[] = [1, 0, 2];
   Output: arr[]   = [102, 101, 103]
   index[] = [0,  1,  2]
```

The founded answers are 
[reorder array according to given index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775994/reorder-array-according-to-given-index)

[php - sort an array according to second given array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695650/php-sort-an-array-according-to-second-given-array)

[Rearrange an array according to key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820887/rearrange-an-array-according-to-key)

[Sorting an Array according to the order of another Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540211/sorting-an-array-according-to-the-order-of-another-array)

Any kind of hint/solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48091007/1410448

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What exactly does not work for you?

```js
const arr = [101, 102, 103];
const index = [1, 0, 2];

const output = index.map(i => arr[i]);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Beware of possible compatibility issues with some versions of browsers, mainly arrow functions https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Answer (score 2):

you can loop and add into new array

```js
var arr    = [101, 102, 103];
var index = [1, 0, 2];
var newArr =[];

for(var i=0;i<index.length ;i++){
   newArr[i]=arr[index[i]]
 }
  console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I rearrange with an array of objects?1: 12,
2: 13,
3: 14,
col: 1,
named_range: "Coll.Par",
row: 1
I want named_range, row ,col first and then 1,2 & 3

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!

Below we use `.map` because it returns a new Array and iterates over `indexes` since we want to sort `unordered` using the `indexes`.

We use the current `index` from `indexes` to pick from `unordered` and return the value.

```
// ES5
var unordered = [101, 102, 103];
var indexes = [1, 0, 2];

var ordered = indexes.map(function(index) {
  return (unordered[index]);
});

console.log(ordered);

// ES6
const unordered = [101, 102, 103];
const indexes = [1, 0, 2];

console.log(
  indexes.map(index => (unordered[index]))
);
```

If you want to get the `indexes` of the `ordered` Array back, you can use the method below.

```
var ordered = indexes.reduce(function(accumulate, index, j) {
  accumulate['values'].push(unordered[index]);
  accumulate['indexes'].push(j);

  return accumulate;
}, { 'values': [], 'indexes': []});

console.log(ordered);
```